# How do I use complex data structures with `ffi`, `ref-struct`, and `ref-array`?

Tags: node.js, node-ffi, ref-struct

I am working on a project that uses `ffi` to interact with a compiled C library. I am trying to get some complex data structures to work and am having problems figuring out the proper way to get values inside these data structures. I have *two* instances I'm trying to figure out. I am *not* a C guy so I'm winging it on that end.

### Instance 1

There is a C `struct` that contains properties that are, what look like pointers to character arrays. Here's the C-code that defines the `struct`:

```
#define RPC_STRING_LENGTH           32
#define RPC_STRING_LENGTH_CALLID    128
typedef struct {
    E_CALL_STATE eCallState;
    BOOL bInboundCall;
    BOOL bVideoCall;
    BOOL bRecording;
    BOOL bEncrypted;
    BOOL bHDAudio;
    BOOL bVirtualMeetingCall;
    E_PROTOCOL_CODEC eCurrentCodec;
    E_PROTOCOL_ALERT_INFO_CALL_TYPE eAlertInfoType;
    double dAccumulatedMOSLQ;
    int  nVideoState;
    int  nErrorCode;
    unsigned int nCallStartTime;
    char cPhoneNumber[RPC_STRING_LENGTH];
    char cName[RPC_STRING_LENGTH];
    char cCallId[RPC_STRING_LENGTH_CALLID];
    char cPreviousCallId[RPC_STRING_LENGTH_CALLID];
} RPC_CALL_STATE;
```

Now, I've been able to successfully extract the `E_CALL_STATE` value *and* the `BOOL` properties but I'm having difficulty getting the strings stores in `cPhoneNumber`, `cName`, `cCallId`, and `cPreviousCallId`. Here's how I have the it setup using `ref-struct`:

```
import ref from 'ref';
import StructType from 'ref-struct';

const RPC_CALL_STATE = StructType({
    eCallState: ref.types.int,
    bInboundCall: ref.types.bool,
    bVideoCall: ref.types.bool,
    bRecording: ref.types.bool,
    bEncrypted: ref.types.bool,
    bHDAudio: ref.types.bool,
    bVirtualMeetingCall: ref.types.bool,
    dAccumulatedMOSLQ: ref.types.double,
    nVideoState: ref.types.int,
    nErrorCode: ref.types.int,
    nCallStartTime: ref.types.uint,
    cPhoneNumber: ref.types.char,
    cName: ref.types.char,
    cCallId: ref.types.char,
    cPreviousCallId: ref.types.char,
});
```

Here's the Javascript that interprets this `struct` (for reference, `RPC_CALL_STATE` is an externally defined `enum`):

```
pDataRef = ref.reinterpret(pData, RPC_CALL_STATE.size);
pDataRef.type = RPC_CALL_STATE;
const callProgressStruct = ref.get(pDataRef);
```

If I look at the value stored on `callProgressStruct.cPhoneNumber`, I get `0`. So, a few questions:

- What is the correct `ref.types` to use here?

  - Is `char` correct?
  - If not, what *should* this be?
- How do I extract the actual string value stored in `cPhoneNumber`?
- Is there a way to use `ref-array` here?

### Instance 2

I have a C `struct` that is defined as such:

```
typedef struct AUDIO_OS_DEVICES {
    int nNumberDevices;
    AUDIO_OS_DEVICE *pDevices;
} AUDIO_OS_DEVICES;
```

In this code, `*pDevices` ends up being an array of `AUDIO_OS_DEVICE` structs. Those structs are defined in C as:

```
typedef struct AUDIO_OS_DEVICE {
    int deviceId;
    int deviceFlags;
    char deviceName[AUDIO_OS_DEVICE_NAME_MAX_LEN];
    char deviceUID[AUDIO_OS_DEVICE_UID_MAX_LEN];
    char manufacturerName[AUDIO_OS_DEVICE_MANUFACTURER_MAX_LEN];
} AUDIO_OS_DEVICE;
```

In Javascript I have this setup using `ref-struct`:

```
const AUDIO_OS_DEVICE = StructType({
  deviceId: ref.types.int,
  deviceFlags: ref.types.int,
  deviceName: ref.types.char,
  deviceUID: ref.types.char,
  manufacturerName: ref.types.char,
});

const AUDIO_OS_DEVICES = StructType({
    nNumberDevices: ref.types.int,
    pDevices: [???],
});
```

I have *no idea* what type to cast `pDevices` to here *nor* do I know how to extract the array of `AUDIO_OS_DEVICE` structs. I am *also* hitting the issue already described with character arrays.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm at a dead-end until I can figure this out.

Comment: Have you tried ref.refType(AUDIO_OS_DEVICE) for pDevices field?

Comment: Did you find a way to do ? I'm looking for the same thing..

Comment: Hey @Alexis_FR_JP: did you find a way?

Comment: No, I think the best would be to make a native module instead of using ffi.